# Text '03-03-1996' could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, localdate

Me aparece ese error cuando intento guardar un EditText tipo date en una variable tipo local date(realizando la conversión adecuada) linea de error en negrita.

**Codigo**

```
public void metodo_editar2(View view) {

    //se añade el contacto

    nombre=campo1.getText().toString();
    papellido=campo2.getText().toString();
    sapellido=campo3.getText().toString();
    direccion=campo4.getText().toString();
    poblacion=campo6.getText().toString();
    //try {
        telefono=Integer.parseInt(campo5.getText().toString());
    //}
    //catch (Exception e){

        advertencia1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //}try {
        fechanacimiento = LocalDate.parse(campo7.getText());


        //convertimos la fecha tipo date en local date
        //fechanacimiento = fechanacimiento.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

        LocalDate fechaactual = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(fechaactual.getYear(), fechanacimiento.getMonthValue(), fechanacimiento.getDayOfMonth());
        if (fechaactual.isAfter(birthday))
            birthday = birthday.plusYears(1);
        Period diff = Period.between(fechaactual, birthday);
        Contacto contacto = new Contacto(nombre, papellido, sapellido, direccion, poblacion, R.drawable.agenda, telefono, fechanacimiento);

        contacto.contactos.add(contacto);

        // se añade el array a la tabla del menu superior


        for (int i = 0; i < contacto.contactos.size(); i++) {


            String n = contacto.contactos.get(i).getNombre();
            LocalDate f = contacto.contactos.get(i).getFechanacimiento();

            //metemos el nombre y el cumpleaños en sus determinadas columnas
            TextView textonombre = new TextView(this);
            TextView textofecha = new TextView(this);
            for (i = 0; i < contacto.contactos.size(); i++)
                textonombre.setText(contacto.contactos.get(i).getNombre());

            //convertimos fecha en string para poder añadirla al texto
            String fechatexto = contacto.contactos.get(i).convertirfecha(contacto.contactos.get(i).getFechanacimiento());

            textofecha.setText(fechatexto);

            //añadimos los atributos a sus respectivas columnas
            tabla2.addView(textonombre);
            tabla2.addView(textofecha);

        }
    }
```

**Archivo XML**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/campo7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="268dp"
    android:hint="Introduce tu fecha de nacimiento aquí(dd-MM-yyyy)"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Fecha"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />
```

Comment: Fijate si no tenés que usar un DateTimeFormatter

Answer (score 1):

El formato por defecto para instanciar una fecha es `AAAA-MM-DD`. Ej.

```
Date   date       = format.parse ( "2009-12-31" );
```

Tu lo tienes al revés `DD-MM-AAAA`: `03-03-1996`

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference Ahora me aparece ese error al añadir el objeto al arraylist contactos

Comment: Eso es otro error que no tiene que ver con lo que preguntaste. Te recomiendo hacer otra pregunta para eso. También recuerda aceptar la pregunta que mas te ayudo con tu pregunta original.

Comment: Al aplicar tu solución y activar el try catch( que esta comentado) por si pone una fecha incorrecta al ejecutar el programa siempre me da como resultado lo que hay en el catch aunque tenga puesta la fecha correcta